# Smartsheets API 2.0 1052 Error "Invalid Accept header. Media type not supported."

Tags: smartsheet-api-2.0

When it submit a curl request on any of the below i get a 1052 error

Sample 1: Get sheet

```
curl https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/%7BsheetId%7D?level=2&include=objectValue 
-H "Authorization: Bearer {token}"
```

Sample 2: Get sheet as Excel

```
curl https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/%7BsheetId%7D 
-H "Authorization: Bearer {token}" 
-H "Accept: application/vnd.ms-excel" 
-o output.xlsx
```

Sample 3: Get sheet as PDF

```
curl 'https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/%7BsheetId%7D?paperSize=A1' 
-H "Authorization: Bearer {token}" 
-H "Accept: application/pdf"
-o  output.pdf
```

Sample 4: Get sheet as CSV

```
curl https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/%7BsheetId%7D 
-H "Authorization: Bearer {token}" 
-H "Accept: text/csv" 
-o output.csv
```

I am expecting to get one of the files types above with the sheet data but instead get the JSON response error in the file.

Comment: Did you solved this one?